# Pegar XHR e setar valores dinamicamente com jQuery Datatables?

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou usando o plugin Jquery [DataTable](http://datatables.net/) e ele funciona, com AJAX, basicamente da seguinte forma:

*Você recebe um JSON da sua requisição e nele precisam conter estes dois dados: ("recordsTotal", "recordsFiltered") e também todos os dados que serão exibidos na tabela para que ocorra a paginação perfeitamente.*

Estou trabalhando, nesta situação, com processamento *ServerSide*. O negócio é que no sistema que utilizo as informações adicionais (estas de paginação) não vem no corpo do JSON e sim nos cabeçalhos de retorno (situação essa que não posso alterar). Então as minhas perguntas são:

- Como faço para capturar estes dados do XHR no retorno pelo *DataTable*?;
- Como faço para setar essas propriedades de ("recordsTotal", "recordsFiltered") com os valores que eu pegar dos cabeçalhos?

Pesquisei bastante e tentei de mil formas possíveis e não consegui ainda chegar na resolução deste problema. O site deles oferece um *debug* então segue o link do *debug* da minha DataTable para o caso de alguém precisar: *Nele contém também o código que estou utilizando.*

[Debug do DataTable()](http://debug.datatables.net/eyebon)

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no código do DataTable e enviei para o proprietário pelo github. Ele não aceitou a exibição do XHR neste momento e disse que irá analisar melhor. O jeito foi alterar o meu código de backend mesmo, infelizmente.

Comment: Mas tem como você postar alguma resposta para a pergunta não ficar solta?

Comment: Pronto, conforme solicitado está publicado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme pedido pelo nosso amigo Maniero estou respondendo a minha pergunta.

Não consegui resolver o problema acima. Fiz um *fork* do projeto no GitHub, alterei o que eu precisava e encaminhei uma *pull request* ao desenvolvedor. Ele agradeceu o envio, mas disse que, no momento, ele não pensa em disponibilizar tal recurso e que irá estudar a viabilidade do mesmo no futuro.

A solução foi fazer ajustes no PHP para poder continuar utilizando o `DataTable`.